# Output panel split in two columns in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

The output in my Sublime Text 3 is split into two columns and only the first column is used. How can I make the output into one column?

[image: Sublime text 3 output panel split screenshot]

Comment: Link in image and I'll edit it in.

Comment: @simonzack thanks. I have added a dropbox link for the images.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this because you probably have the following settings:

```js
"rulers": [80], // shows ruler
"word_wrap": true,
"wrap_width": 80 // hard wraps at this column
```

These preferences affect all views, however, you can get rid of this behavior by setting:

```js
"wrap_width": 0 // wraps at edge of screen
```

and keeping the `"rulers"` setting the way it is. This way, you'll still have the visual indication that you're getting close to your 80-char limit (or whatever you're using, I'm assuming 80 because of PEP-8), and you can manually wrap your line or refactor to shorten it as needed. The ruler will still show in the build pane, but the text will not wrap.

### **EDIT**

If you really feel like hacking, there **is** a way to assign setting just to the build panel. It involves messing with `exec.py`, which runs the build systems, but the changes are relatively minor. First, since you're using ST3, you'll need to extract the file from the `Default` package. Install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) via Package Control, then open the Command Palette and type ***`prv`*** to bring up the **P**ackage**R**esource**V**iewer options. Select **`Edit Package Resource`**, scroll down to `Default`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, scroll down to `exec.py`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. Next, select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages`** to open your `Packages` folder, whose location varies by operating system, in your OS's file system viewer (Explorer, Finder, Nautilus, etc.). Open the `Default` folder, then open `exec.py` in Sublime.

Scroll down to line 146, where you should see a block of code like so:

```py
if (working_dir == "" and self.window.active_view()
                and self.window.active_view().file_name()):
    working_dir = os.path.dirname(self.window.active_view().file_name())
# line 146
self.output_view.settings().set("result_file_regex", file_regex)
self.output_view.settings().set("result_line_regex", line_regex)
self.output_view.settings().set("result_base_dir", working_dir)
self.output_view.settings().set("word_wrap", word_wrap)
self.output_view.settings().set("line_numbers", False)
self.output_view.settings().set("gutter", False)
```

Add an extra line after line 146, then put in:

```py
self.output_view.settings().set("rulers", [])
self.output_view.settings().set("wrap_width", 0)
```

Save the file, and you should be all set! Your build panels should now behave as expected, with no ruler and the text wrapping at the full size of the pane, instead of at column 80. All of your other views will keep the setting you already have.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer. I am a new user of ST3 and just checked my settings, which are:  `"word_wrap": "auto"`  "wrap_width": 0  "rulers": []

Comment: @harryw which settings did you check? Make sure it's `Preferences -> Settings-User`.

Comment: I checked Preferences -> Settings-Default, but Preferences -> Settings-User i have    {
 "color_scheme": "Packages/User/Monokai (SL).tmTheme",
 "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Vintage"
 ],
 "theme": "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme"
}

Comment: @harryw if you go into the `View` menu, make sure `Word Wrap Column` is set to `Automatic` and `Ruler` is set to `None`.

Comment: BTW, I added indented four spaces in front of  {  "color_scheme": but still cannot create a code block here. Sorry for asking irrelevant question.

Comment: Yes. I changed that, which changed the code panel but the output panel is still the same.

Comment: @harryw to use code in comments, you need to use backticks (the key  to the left of 1 on US keyboards, `), which also works for inline code in questions/answers. Did you rerun your build after changing the menu items? You may also need to restart Sublime. Try that out and let me know.

Comment: @harryw by rerunning the build, I mean closing the build window, then running it clean so that it opens a new pane.

Comment: I get "Unable to find target command: exec" if I modify those settings.

Comment: nvm there were some spaces and tabs problems easily resolved.

Comment: Excellent tip.
However, instead of using prv, I extracted the exec.py from the Default.sublime-package package (it's just a zip) and placed the modified exec.py in `%appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default` (created the folder)
Only modified the line
`self.output_view.settings().set("word_wrap", word_wrap)`
to
`self.output_view.settings().set("word_wrap", False)`
Cheers!